# I am trying send xml as input to param in xslt, but it is not parsing the xml input

Tags: xml, xslt, apache-camel

Hi I am trying to send below xml as input to xslt param.

The xml input is like :

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><map><entry key="25812926">1</entry></map>
```

and want to extract key value using xslt code as below
parse-xml($items)/map/entry[@key = '25812926']"

Here items is the parameter name for xml input.

Comment: Can you tell us which XSLT processor you use with Camel, can you show us the relevant part of the XSLT (parameter declaration)? Which error or result do you get? `parse-xml` exists in XPath 3 and therefore XSLT 3. Also, how do you pass in the XML? Is it passed in as a string?

Comment: in camel I am calling xslt by <to id="XsltCall" uri="xslt-saxon:./xslt/TestXslT.xsl" /> .  I have formed a string in xml way and passing it as parameter/input

Comment: Please show the relevant XSLT code for the parameter declaration and tell us exactly which error or result you get.